# How to call a JavaScript function within dynamically generated html inside a html container

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function related to a dynamically generated list inside of an HTML container div.
My HTML has the app container, where the panel class lives, and that's where the list is going from the populateCustomerList() function.
The myFunction() is being called in the onkeyup but it's returning an Uncaught Reference error myFunction() is not defined.

My goal is to be able to search within the dynamically generated html.

HTML:

```
<div id="app-container">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3 id="C-List">Customers</h3>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for customers.."> 
</input>
        <div id="customer-list-container"></div>
        <input type="button" id="btnGetCustomerList" value="Get Customers">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function populateCustomerList(jsonArr){                
    
    var html = "";
            
    for(var x = 0; x < jsonArr.length; x++){
                                
        html += `
        <ul id="myUL">
            <li customerId = "${jsonArr[x].customerId}">
            <a href="#"><strong>Customer Name:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].customerName} 
            <br><strong>Main Phone:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainPhone} 
            <br><strong>Main Email:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainEmail}
            <br><strong>Bill To Address:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo1},<br>
                    ${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo2},<br>
                    ${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo3}
                    <br></a>
                    <input type="button" class= "btnEdit" value="EDIT">
                </li>
        </ul>`
    }
    
    var ol = document.createElement("ol");
    ol.innerHTML = html;

    var tableContainer = document.getElementById("customer-list-container");
    tableContainer.innerHTML = "";
    tableContainer.appendChild(ol);

    tableContainer.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    //populateCardGroupList();
    var target = evt.target;
    //if statement to see if the classList has a button edit
        if(target.classList.contains("btnEdit")){
            //get the id of the card group clicked
            var selectedId = target.closest("li").getAttribute("customerId");
            //get the card group attached to that id and pass it the rest of the json Array of objects
            var selectedCustomer = getCustomerId(selectedId, jsonArr);
            populateCustomerForm(selectedCustomer);
        }
    });
    
}

function myFunction(){
    var input, filter, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding the event handler in js instead of html?
const myInput =document.getElementById('myInput'); myInput.addEventListener('keyup',function(){myFunction()});

Comment: I have tried using document.getElementById, and passing myFunction() through and it doesn't work.

Comment: well, when it doesn't work: what specifically doesn't work, is myFunction still undefined?

Comment: So it partially works actually, I was just searching for the first item in the list. When searching the results are sort of close but not all of the other ones are hiding when i type in the search bar

Comment: If I search for something at the bottom of the list, only what was at the top of the list prior to searching disappears. So if the list is A, B, C, D and I seach for D - Only A disappears and i'm left with a list that is B, C, D in that order.

Comment: Believe your issue is with how you're building your list when executing `html += ...`.  For every item, you are building `<ul> <li>...</li> </ul>`, rather than `<ul> <li>...</li> <li>...</li> </ul>`.  Thus, myFunction is only picking up the first `<ul>`, which only contains one `<li>`...

Comment: 90% sure that is the answer.... on another note: personally, i find chunking in new html via a text paste a bit of a code-smell. consider declaring them in JS and looping in data via .map(); it will be easier to read, and it will be easier to prove logically :).

Comment: @altruios oddly there is a HTML templating capability (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) that seems to encourage this "html text" design pattern, but it looks even more fraught with subtleties that can obscure the application logic!

Comment: oh, interesting, i've been taught to avoid that, and use variables for element creation since that is way easier to target anything with, and placing on the DOM more fluid, I stopped the text to html pattern when I moved from php to node...

Comment: but even for that link, that's still cloning elements templated in html... I'm talking about using document.createElement('div'); for pretty much everyhing.

Comment: @altruios the `createElement()` method is typically what I use too, although occasionally I do use the text-to-HTML pattern for really complex HTML, just to make the DOM outcome more readable, with an eye towards long term code maintainability.  I'm sure the text-to-HTML design pattern introduces a performance hit, but if this isn't a super high volume site, I figure it is a fair trade off...

Comment: I wasn't thinking performance, but for logical evaluation. when you start generating text and applying html via text blocks after they've been generated, event handles don't get attached until they've been defined, which is after the first load... which means you need to account for places where things load into the dom after the first render... is messy logically quickly. much better to have one load if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment, following the design pattern, believe the head end of the `populateCustomerList` needs to separate out the `ul` tag, so that there's a single `ul` tag for all the enclosed `li` list items.

```
 var html = "";
 
 html += `<ul id="myUL">`;

    for(var x = 0; x < jsonArr.length; x++){
                                
        html += `
            <li customerId = "${jsonArr[x].customerId}">
            <a href="#"><strong>Customer Name:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].customerName} 
            <br><strong>Main Phone:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainPhone} 
            <br><strong>Main Email:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainEmail}
            <br><strong>Bill To Address:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo1},
                    <br>${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo2},
                    <br>${jsonArr[x].mainBillTo3}
                    <br></a>
                    <input type="button" class= "btnEdit" value="EDIT">
                </li>`;
    }

html += `</ul>`;
```

Comment: That works great, thank you very much for your help! I understand this code as well!